# Setting up an Ant script to upload files

Tags: file, ant, upload

I've run over only a few examples of how to do this and they didn't work for me. Mainly since i've only used an ant script to auto build jar files threw jenkins. Now though i need to build those files in jenkins then upload them to a 3rd party file site like sourceforge. This is both to save hard drive space on the server, since i don't own it, and to allow external downloads. Any help is welcome but no comments on the fact i don't know to much about ant scripts.

Also something related by a bit separate.The jar file i'm building depends on a another jar file with its own version.  i also want to make a new folder each time it uploads with a different dependency version. This way the users that download this file can easily understand the main jar version it goes with while allowing me to upload 20+ sub builds.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to upload files, so there are several kind of ant tasks to do the job.

For instance, if you want to upload to sourceforge, you can use the Ant task [`scp`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html). But it seems also possible to upload there via FTP: so here is the task [`ftp`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html).

Maybe you find some other service which requires you to upload via HTTP: [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) have the [`post`](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/post_task.html) task.

Comment: Thank you those links might just work especial with the example code at the bottom of them.

Answer (score 0):

I used to do publications as part of my ANT build logic, creating a special "publish" target that issued the scp or ftp command.Now I'm more inclined to leverage one of the [publish over plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over) for Jenkins.

The main reason for this shift is the management of access credentials. Using the ANT based approach I was forced to run my build on a Jenkins slave that was pre-configured with the correct SSH key to talk to the remote server. The Jenkins plugin manages private keys centrally and ensures all slaves are properly configured.

Finally if your build has dependencies on 3rd party jars, use a dependency manager like [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to download them and include them in your project. It then becomes trivial to include their upload as part of your publish step.

Comment: thanks i'm going to try that plugin, at least try to get the server owner to install it, if i can't get the ant script to do it strait out.